# installation of wine

Tags: command-line, wine

i was trying to install wine on ubuntu 14.04. I used the command `sudo apt-get install wine`. A complete process was worked out. Around 140 MB data was downloaded from the internet but suddenly it was interrupted. after then when tried to run the same command again it gave me the following message:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

please suggest remedy to the problem. I am new to ubuntu community.
Thanks

Comment: I did not down vote your question , but you were downvoted because you did not describe what you did to get this error and i t appear you did not read the error message .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error message tells you what happened " dpkg was interrupted" meaning it stopped in the middle of installing something. Can you tell use how that happened ? did something crash ? did you stop it ?

And also how to correct the problem "you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem,"

So, open a terminal and run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

post any problems that you get when your run that command ;)

If you get no errors, it is fixed.

Comment: thanks..it worked.Actually it was interrupted when my internet connection was lost.